# Is it really required to escape backslashes in regex patterns?

Tags: php, regex, string, escaping, string-literals

This might be a dumb question, but I have trouble understanding why the following code works as expected

```
$text = "ab    cd";
$text = preg_replace("/\s+/", "", $text);
echo $text;
```

and outputs `abcd`.

Shouldn't the backslash in `\s` be escaped to get its literal meaning inside the regular expression?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Not necessarily, because the [string literal rules](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.single) say that if `\` is followed by anything other than another `\` or a `'` it is treated as any other character. This general rule also affects double-quoted strings, although [in that case](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.double) there are more recognized escape sequences than just these two.

You *could* escape it if you wanted to, but personally I think the world has enough backslashes already.

Comment: +1. It gets really confusing when you realise that even some characters that would be picked up by PHP as escape sequences don't need to be double-escaped because the escaped character is valid inside the regex. So you can get away with `\n`, or you can escape it `\\n`. But where it really gets bad is when you have an actual backslash in your string to search for. Try matching a Windows network path (`\\nas\folder\etc\`) or a find escaped characters in a JSON string, and you'll end up with a monstrous cascade of backslashes. Fun fun fun.